# Leaflet dynamically change marker color based on value passed to function

Tags: leaflet

I have some JavaScript code that looks like the following:

```
<script type='module'>
import { circleOptions } from './colors.js';
...
...
value = do_math_on_some_number(number)
const circle = L.circle([lat,lon],circleOptions).addTo(map);
...
...
</script>
```

where lat = latitude, lon = longitude, and value = some integer value between 1-4. In a separate file where I call my variable circleOptions:

```
export var circleOptions = {
        color: customColormap(3),
        radius: 1000,
};
```

I then have a simple function to create a colormap:

```
function customColormap(value) {
        const colorStops = [0,1,2,3,4];
        const colors = ['#FF0000', '#FF6600', '#FFFF00', '#33FF33', '#0066FF']
  // Find the appropriate color based on the value
  for (let i = 1; i < colorStops.length; i++) {
    if (value < colorStops[i]) {
        return colors[i]
    }
  }
}
```

I have placed a '3' at in the circleOptions value of customColormap, and alter this to be 1, 2, 3, and can view the colors changing for each of my lat/lon datapoints. The idea now would be to turn circleOptions into a function that a number (whatever value might be, 1, 2, 3, or 4) can be passed into it, and that number is used as the input to customColormap (such as the commented-out portion below the actual call). In other words, I would want something like:

```
<script type='module'>
import { circleOptions } from './colors.js';
...
...
value = do_math_on_some_number(number)
const circle = L.circle([lat,lon],circleOptions(value)).addTo(map);
...
...
</script>
```

With the new circleOptions being:

```
export function circleOptions(vaule) = {
        color: customColormap(value),
        radius: 1000,
};
```

I have tried several different things and am stuck. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: In title you write "dynamically change marker color". Do you want to set color only at the time of marker definition or also later, after marker was defined?

Comment: I guess the marker could just be some 'default' value (zero?) until defined, and it would stay defined based on the 'value' passed via the function

Comment: You didn't clearly answer my question: do you want to dynamically change marker color later, after it was initially defined?

Comment: no. Once the color is defined, it will stay that color.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the JS syntax you are using (probably ES6), so I can't test your code, but I noticed that `export function circleOptions(vaule)` has parameter `vaule`, which does not match `color: customColormap(value)` usage.